# Erro a publicar numa fanpage facebook usando php

Tags: php, facebook

Tenho em dois servidores exactamente o mesmo código php. O código faz a partilha de conteúdo do meu site numa fanpage. A questão é que em um dos servidores o código deixou de funcionar e aparece o seguinte erro da imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver este problema? Será que o servidor bloqueou o dominio facebook? Ou será outro problema por exemplo extensões do php(módulos/Bibliotecas)?

Nota: o código já funcionou neste servidor, mas por algum motivo deixou de funcionar agora.
O código que estou a usar está no seguinte link: [aqui](http://www.douglaspasqua.com/2013/02/09/facebook-sdk-publicando-fotos-na-fan-page-com-access-token/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que qualquer que seja a url que você está hospedando o seu aplicativo não está configurado na sua configuração do aplicativo.

Vá para as configurações do aplicativo(https://developers.facebook.com/apps) e garanta que as *urls* **estejam iguais**. Você tem duas opções para entrar: `http://www.Foobar.com` ou `http://Foobar.com`. Seu aplicativo vai funcionar com apenas um deles.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sub>[`Fonte`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345777/given-url-is-not-allowed-by-the-application-configuration)</sub>

Comment: sim, já tinha verificado esta questão e tenho tudo correcto. obrigado!